# java webstart startup delay on virtual server

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

We have an annoying problem with java web start. We have a huge java application with about 75 jar-files that our users start on our virtual (hyper-v) remote desktop servers. 
The application starts ok, first displaying a splash screen via the jnlp icon tag, then we get the webstart downloading and verifying jar files, and eventually the application starts. The problem is that we have a 8-9-10 second gap between the "verifying application" dialog closes before our application actually starts (and the java console is visible, if this is activated).
This gap is so huge that many of our users actually double-click on our application icon to start it again because they think something is wrong.
I have now patiently tested a lot, and come up with the following:

- There is no huge gap when starting the application on a local pc instead of the virtual remote desktop server. It only happens on our remote servers (we have multiple, and it happens on all of them)
- If I comment out almost all the jar-files, the gap is reduced a lot, but it still exists for 3-4 seconds.
- The following line affects the gap heavily:

  ```
  <j2se version="1.6+" java-vm-args="-Xmx1300m" />
  ```

If the java-vm-args are omitted, or set to a very low number, the gap goes away completely! However, we cannot do this. It is a big app that needs a lot of memory for processing.

- If I try running as a standalone application, eg java -jar -Xmx1300m application.jar  ,there is no gap!

What is the reason that running as a standalone application, there is no gap before the application starts, but running as webstart, we get the big gap before the application starts? And why only on our virtual remote desktop servers, and not on local pcs too? What strange quirks does the jp2launcher.exe do, and how do we come around them?
Btw, tried switching between dynamic and static memory for one of the servers in hyper-v, without any difference.

Comment: Is the same gap observed on subsequent web-start startup times?

Comment: @Leet-Falcon good question. Maybe something cache related? Have you tried preloading the system cache?

Comment: Yes it is observed on subsequent startups. Updated jar-files increase the download dialog time, but the gap between the dialog and the actual start stays the same.

Comment: Maybe your remote desktop servers have slow connection to sites which verify your certificate? Check your Timestamping Authority (-tsa argument for jarsigner) - maybe this server is slow? If you would avoid this problem you can use [Ice Boar](https://github.com/Roche/IceBoar) in your application. Then only Ice Boar needs to be verified.